# Entries not visible on Production

Tags: entries, structure

I have a Structure called `Pages` which works great on my localhost. When it comes to deploying the website i'm not sure what the issue is.

Before I deploy; I am running `./craft settings/rebuild`. If I check my `config/project.yml` file it contains this:

```
sections:
  21e80bf5-5bf0-4acd-89fa-e108f377f367:
    name: Pages
    handle: Pages
    type: structure
    enableVersioning: true
    propagationMethod: all
    siteSettings:
      0bbf44af-5493-45e6-a8fd-711fbf205c27:
        enabledByDefault: true
        hasUrls: true
        uriFormat: '{parent.uri}/{slug}'
        template: pages/page
      62a954cf-14e6-4afc-a4ee-721a1fa504ce:
        enabledByDefault: true
        hasUrls: true
        uriFormat: '{parent.uri}/{slug}'
        template: pages/page
      b24e91d9-c16e-4418-a2be-f784c1a5db73:
        enabledByDefault: true
        hasUrls: true
        uriFormat: '{parent.uri}/{slug}'
        template: pages/page
      dcd40638-52ee-4f8e-944b-be8663f015d6:
        enabledByDefault: true
        hasUrls: true
        uriFormat: '{parent.uri}/{slug}'
        template: pages/page
    structure:
      uid: 3051f9fb-d940-42a7-a2bf-1a4dcfbf0bfe
      maxLevels: null
    entryTypes:
      33ed925f-348c-4c9d-bf8e-a18f36ffa2f9:
        name: Homepage
        handle: homepage
        hasTitleField: true
        titleLabel: Title
        titleFormat: ''
        sortOrder: 2
        fieldLayouts:
          b04b3c2b-b371-4c33-8813-5dd41ba38143:
            tabs:
              -
                name: Content
                sortOrder: 1
                fields:
                  7dfc068b-dcde-47e8-92ab-17054e23cd28:
                    required: false
                    sortOrder: 2
      96020cb2-dbdb-42c7-bcae-66762fd7b98c:
        name: Page
        handle: page
        hasTitleField: true
        titleLabel: Title
        titleFormat: ''
        sortOrder: 1
        fieldLayouts:
          63ce77f0-af11-4304-b21d-c1bc6d0c8bb6:
            tabs:
              -
                name: Content
                sortOrder: 1
                fields:
                  0556df33-f19f-4a6e-a26b-73be1b719674:
                    required: false
                    sortOrder: 1
                  7dfc068b-dcde-47e8-92ab-17054e23cd28:
                    required: false
                    sortOrder: 2
```

When I deploy my changes and run `./craft project-config/sync` the Entries section isn't showing up in Admin.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Is it a problem with the URLs maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Notice you got
`handle: Pages`

And in code below
`template: pages/page`

A lucky guess would be, your local is not case sensitive. As you might running it on a windows machine with a virtual host. 
However, your server ,if its a Linux server, it is likely to be case sensitive.
So I will suggest you change your `handle: Pages` to `handle: pages`

Comment: When you mean, entries sections not showing up. Do you see any errors when you go to entry section? If not, probably just export the database from local and import to deploy environment again.